# Edit box Highlight in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have developed android app which `highlighted edit box default in android 2.1-3.0` but after downloaded **android sdk 4.0 the edit box became white**,
 Any one can help me to highlight the edit box by giving border such that,,

my existing edit box xml is

```
    EditText
    android:id="@+id/shoutoutmsgfield"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:ems="10"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can assign a selector drawable to its background property